# ¿Como puedo tener un directorio en un proyecto Django para almacenar las apps que vaya creando?

Tags: python, django

Quiero crear un Dir en mi proyecto Django donde pueda guardar las aplicaciónes que vaya creando, por ejemplo: polls, portfolio, blog, etc.
Tener almacenadas esas apps en un solo directorio.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una directorio en tu proyecto llamado "  `apps`, luego en el `settings.py` puedes poner ejemplo:

```
NSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.humanize',
# external apps
# local apps
'apps.tu_app',
```

apps = Tu directorio creado por ti

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que crear un nuevo directorio y crear dentro de el un archivo _ _init__.py y pasar tus app allí

```
----dir_apps
  +
  --------__init__.py
  +
  --------polls
  +
  --------portfolio
  +
  --------blog
  +
  --------etc
```

Y en tu installed_apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'dir_apps.polls',
  'dir_apps.portfolio',
  ...
)
```